# Check field value before publishing post (wordpress)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have in my editor many custom fields defined, from many sources (various plugins and also hardcoded php).

How can I check when I hit the post button if a specific field has been field (if $_POST['field'] has any value) and if not, don't allow the post to be published.

In other words make it a mandatory field.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Two complementary validations:

1) Client-side validation in JS/jQuery:

Check on an event (click, blur etc) if the specific field is empty, then return false for the submission of the form, else submit it anyway.

2) Server-side validation in PHP:

If `$_POST['field']` is empty, then redirect to the form page with the filled contents with the specific field being flagged for empty content. Otherwise, allow the post to be published.

You can have suit these validations according to your needs.

Comment: And how to implement that in the posting?